# Importing Flat Files in SSIS using @FileName as the destination table

Tags: import, ssis, flat-file

I'm trying to import a large number of flatfiles using SSIS, but the thing is I wanted to use foreach, so that it could get the name of the file and use it as the table destination name.

For example:

**Flat File name: ExampleOfFile.txt**

***foreach executes, gets the file's name and stores in variable @FileName***

**Destination table: [dbo].[ExampleOfFile]**

Do you guys have any thoughts on how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: can you give more of an example, copy your code and show where your problem is really at. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This post shows a great example.  Check other posts by Jaime to find out just about how to do anything in SSIS: http://consultingblogs.emc.com/jamiethomson/archive/2005/05/30/SSIS_3A00_-Enumerating-files-in-a-Foreach-loop.aspx